# making REST kinds of urls in simple servlet like {resource}/<id>

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I am making a web service which is REST based.

First i wants to see url like as follows

```
 /{resource}
 /{resource}/<id>
 /{resource1}/<id>/{resource2}
 /{resource1}/<id>/{resource2}/<id>
```

How to make servlet urls as above..?
I prefer not to use any framework.

Comment: Don't try reinventing the wheel. Have a look at JAX-RS using Netbeans and you will see how easy things are. Don't bother with a custom solution that will never be a complete one.Use the wizards and everything will be created for you.Create your entities and from your entities create your REST services

Comment: There are lots of library of REST development you can use those like JERSEY,Spring MVC.

Comment: correct me if wrong but most of the times i realized that framework make request and response slower because most of the times we do not use all the resources whatever they gives.

Comment: Kuku, the developers of JAX-RS or Restlet or any REST services library out there catered for performance already.Also try to be as standard as possible because in the end most probably you won't be the only developer working on the project you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet API doesn't provide any special support for this kind of mapping.

If you want to do it without third-party libraries, you need to map your servlet to `/{resource}`, get rest of the path as `request.getPathInfo()` and implement further routing based on that value:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    ...
    <url-pattern>/resource</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

.

```
public class ResourceServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String path = request.getPathInfo();
        if (path == null) { // It's /resource
            ...
        } else if (path.matches("/\\d+")) { // It's /resources/<id> with integer id
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, it would be better not to reinvent the wheel and use one of JAX-RS implementations.

Comment: correct me if wrong but most of the times i realized that framework make request and response slower because most of the times we do not use all the resources whatever they gives.